# Getting Into Game Development

Tags: java

After a bit of research (And a bit of experimenting) I found that coding is quite fun. I've always wanted to try game development, but never really found a place to start. As well as this, this is my first time using Stack Exchange, so if this post is horrendously misplaced, I apologise. I don't want to go into professional game development, as I'm only 13, but I would like to try it. As I said before, I did try some programming (In Java), so I know the very basics of code-Java at least-so this is my question:
How would I go about building a simple platformer? I don't want fancy graphics, or multiple states. All I want to try is the code a simple engine that can use collisions and take keyboard input, and have a single level that can be changed within the code (By that I just mean drawing different sized rectangles). That is it. 
How would I go about this, in the simplest way possible? Any help would be appreciated! :D

Comment: We don't answer "how to start" type questions, please read our [help]

Comment: It's great you're getting started so early! Do some more research. Keep in mind that game development is not the same as engine development (which you talk about both in your post/title). Look at job posting descriptions to get an idea of the technologies out there and what kind of roles people fill. This isn't the site for getting started questions, but we can certainly help you along the way once you have questions that are appropriate for this site.

Comment: check out `javax.swing`. It's easy to learn games through swing, as i have made MANY. You can make games with buttons, panels, images, movement, and much, much more. If you get to 20 reputation be sure to visit the java chat room. You can ask questions like this there.

Comment: (cont.) also java.awt.Graphics is not "Fancy" at all. It is really easy to learn. You can draw pretty much any shape you want with java.awt.Graphics. Have fun coding!